# Why webRTC get blocked by secure networks and apps such as Sandboxie?

Tags: vpn, sandboxie, webrtc

Am currently working on webRTC video conference app and whenever a user installs a security app such as Sandboxie, webRTC is totally blocked (apart from signalling).
I have also tried to create a live broadcast with sandboxie enabled on Younow, appr.tc and they dont work too.. So am certain that it impossible to bi-pass such a  security. Am asking these because one of my client argues to be on VPN connections and WebRTC is not working on his side. He is using latest chrome browser that supports the webRTC. Its unprofessional for me to ask my client to turn off the VPN so that he can access WebRTC... I have tried so many options, I even tried working with twilio programmable video API (uses weRTC) and it was also blocked. Keep in mind all this trials works with other clients (ofcourse who dont use extensive security). After i use sandboxie, i experience the same thing as the client. The client repeatedly says he is only on VPN. Do VPN block WebRTC? What could it be??

Comment: Sandboxie does not guarantee compatibility with every application.

Comment: The client is not on sandboxie but the VPN connection he is using behaves like sandboxie.. Do VPN block WebRTC?

Comment: I was just trying to explain the reason WebRTC would not function properly within a Sandboxie instance.  I suggest comparing apples to apples in your efforts to debug the situation.

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely a security measure, since WebRTC can leak all your internal IP-addresses though the VPN.

Differente VPNs handle this WebRTC vulnerability in different ways; some block the leaks, some block WebRTC altogether.